# Entity Framework Coluna extra ao usar ICollection

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Se eu tiver duas tabelas no banco, por exemplo: `tabela1` e `tabela2`, e na `tabela1` eu tiver uma `ICollection` da `tabela2`:

```
public class tabela1{

   public Guid tabela1Id {get;set;}

  //campos...

  public ICollection <tabela2> tabela2 {get;set;}

}
```

O Entity Framework vai criar um index(uma coluna a mais na `tabela2`) da `tabela1` na `tabela2`, com a chave primaria da `tabela1` com o nome de: `tabela1_tabela1Id`

Como eu posso evitar que ele crie essa coluna a mais? Ou como eu posso mudar o nome que ele da à essa coluna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não concordo muito com essa nomenclatura de `tabela` até porque o Entity Framework é agnóstico quanto a banco de dados, então não necessariamente ele opera no modelo relacional, apenas em cima de tabelas. Ele vai além disso. Mas voltando à resposta:

Tendo esta declaração:

```
public class tabela1 
{

   public Guid tabela1Id {get;set;}

  //campos...

  public ICollection <tabela2> tabela2 {get;set;}
}
```

Você precisa ter esta:

```
public class tabela2
{
    [Key]
    public Guid tabela2id { get; set; }
    // Anote também a FK, assim:
    public Guid tabela1id { get; set; }

    public virtual tabela1 tabela1 { get; set }
}
```

Isto gera a FK com o nome `tabela1id`.

Agora, se você quer outro nome para a FK, use o [`[ForeignKey]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) da seguinte forma:

```
public class tabela2
{
    [Key]
    public Guid tabela2id { get; set; }
    // Anote também a FK, assim:
    public Guid MinhaFKCujoNomeEuEscolhi { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MinhaFKCujoNomeEuEscolhi")]
    public virtual tabela1 tabela1 { get; set }
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
public class tabela2
{
    [Key]
    public Guid tabela2id { get; set; }
    // Anote também a FK, assim:
    [ForeignKey("MinhaPropriedadeDeNavegacaoCujoNomeEuEscolhi")]
    public Guid tabela1id { get; set; }

    public virtual tabela1 MinhaPropriedadeDeNavegacaoCujoNomeEuEscolhi { get; set }
}
```

Comment: Essa nomenclatura usei só como exemplo aqui, e isso é possível de ser feito usando Fluent API ?

Comment: É possível, mas eu acho a Fluent API mais complicada de usar.